# Implicit List Initialization Constructors for Structs

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

GCC 5.4 compiles this without any warnings (using `-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic`):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Coord {
    double x, y;
};

Coord origin() {
    return {0.0, 0.0};
}

int main() {
    Coord c = origin();
    std::cout << "(" << c.x << ", " << c.y << ")\n";
}
```

It looks like `{0.0, 0.0}` creates an `std::initializer_list` that gets used to construct to a Coord, even though I haven't defined such a constructor.

Do structs have implicit conversion constructors for an `std::initializer_list`? If so, what are the rules for when this constructor is generated and how it works? If not, why does this compile without warning?

Comment: [Aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and [`return` statement, form (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return). Brace-init list can appear in `return` statement, in which case the return value is initialized from it, similar to `Coord ret{0.0, 0.0}; return ret;`

Comment: Thanks, a link to Aggregate initialization page and a brief summary of what counts as an aggregate and the rules for the braced-init-list would make an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

> “Similarly, we can initialize objects of a class for which we have not
>   defined a constructor using • memberwise initialization, • copy
>   initialization, or • default initialization (without an initializer or
>   with an empty initializer list). For example:

```
struct Work {
     string author;
     string name;
     int year;
};

Work s9 { "Beethoven",
          "Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125; Choral",
          1824
      };                         // memberwise initialization

Work currently_playing { s9 };   // copy initialization
Work none {};                    // default initialization”
```

Excerpt From: Bjarne Stroustrup. “The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition.”

Also, here's cppreference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> class type (typically, struct or union), that has no private or
>   protected non-static data members no user-provided, inherited, or
>   explicit (since C++17) constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted
>   constructors are allowed) (since C++11) no virtual, private, or
>   protected (since C++17) base classes no virtual member functions no
>   default member initializers

Which is an excerpt from an extended description of the above. In human it means if you have a simple class you can initialise it using a list of the appropriate types, laid out in the same way. The cppref page shows how you can even nest the types as long as those criteria hold.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your final sentence: the members of an aggregate don't have to be aggregates .

Comment: `Work none {};` isn't default-initialization for aggregates (maybe this is a mistake in the book, if you quoted correctly). Default-initialization would be `Work none;`  , but adding the `{}` gives different behaviour (namely, that each member is initialized as if by `{}`, and in this example it means `year` gets `0`)

Comment: My quote is a copy-paste. But it's for C++11. Are we talking 2017?

Comment: I believe `Work none{}` was value-initialization in 2003. Terminology was changed in the 2003 standard; between 1998 and 2003 "default-initialization" meant roughly what value-initialization means now; since 2003, default-initialization means roughly "no initialization, or call constructor", and value-initialization means roughly "zero initialization or call constructor". Perhaps the section you quoted was overlooked during revision of that edition

Comment: I think it's important to note in the answer that structs do _not_ have an implicit conversion constructor from `std::initializer_list`s. As Igor commented on the question, since C++11, this is a special form of return statement that constructs the value using copy-list-initialization, which in this case uses aggregate initialization, instead of trying to find a constructor with an `std::initializer_list` as it's only parameter.